# how to drop a row where a particular column value is not date and all the column are of string type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1          col2      col3
01/01/10      abc       pqr
10/10/18      sps       ggg
date          pqp       fdf
03/12/19      rt        sd
summary       re        ss
```

all the columns are of string type, I want to drop those rows where the value is other than any date.

The output df should look like

```
df
col1          col2      col3
01/01/10      abc       pqr
10/10/18      sps       ggg
03/12/19      rt        sd
```

how to do it in most efficient way in python ?

Comment: Also how about this solution, didnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
df2[df2.apply(lambda x: True if len(re.findall('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}',x.col1)) >= 1 else False, axis=1)]
```

**Output**

```
      col1 col2 col3
0  01/01/10  abc  pqr
1  10/10/18  sps  ggg
3  03/12/19  rt   sd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors=‘coerce’`:
from the docs:

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.col1,errors='coerce').dropna().index]
```

---

```
       col1 col2 col3
0  01/01/10  abc  pqr
1  10/10/18  sps  ggg
3  03/12/19   rt   sd
```

Or if you want the `col1` to be a datetime column use:

```
df.col1=pd.to_datetime(df.col1,errors='coerce')
df[df.col1.notna()]
```